# "Restaurant food isn't good for babies (just) as well as breast milk isn't fit for adults." — Does the presence of "just" affect the sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we always replace "*as well as*" with "*just as well as*"?
Can we always replace "*just as well as*" with "*as well as*"?

If not, then when can we and when not?

---

[merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just%20as):
**(1)** *She performs **just as well as** he does*.
I think "*just*" doesn't change the sentence meaning and is needed to make the sentence more expressive and emphatic so we can remove it:
**(2)** *She performs **as well as** he does*.

---

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/as-well-as.3558179/):

> **(3)** *Restaurant food isn't good for babies **as well as** breast milk isn't fit for adults*. — incorrect
> **(4)** *Restaurant food isn't good for babies **just as** breast milk isn't fit for adults*. — correct

By analogy with (1) and (2), we can use "*just*" in (3) and the sentence meaning (and therefore its correctness) mustn't change.
That means if (3) is incorrect, then "(3) + just" will be incorrect too:
**(5)** *Restaurant food isn't good for babies **just as well as** breast milk isn't fit for adults*. — incorrect

Am I right that (5) is also incorrect [as (3) is]?
If not, then why not?

Comment: Your questions are very abrupt. Ever considered using a please or a thank you?

Comment: @BillJ I like the words "thank you" very much. But unfortunately the ELL community doesn't like it. When I wrote "thanks" at the end of my posts, there were always users who deleted it by editing my posts. I even wrote "thanks (don't delete it please)" one time but someone still deleted it (((

Comment: I think it is meant for comments. Not for posts...

Comment: @Lambie unfortunately someone in the world of Stack Exchange argued that "Thanks" and "Pleases" were noise, and did not add anything to posts. SO users were encouraged to delete these pleasantries, and as we all know, many users on ELL and ELU are also users on Stack Overflow. The culture was, and to many still remains, that signing off with "Thanks in advance" is fluff and should be edited out whenever it rears its apologetic head. See this [9-year-old answer by J.R](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4541/44619) at EL&U meta.

Answer (score 3):

The *as well as* is a comparative form of adverb that applies to **active** verbs.
well, better, best

He **speaks** as well as she does.
She **performs** as well as he does. [sample sentence from OP].
You can use just or not. Your choice.

However, *as well as* cannot go with a **be** verb, which is stative, since be verbs don't "take" adverbs.

BUT: **as well as** can be used for "and", as a conjunction.

- Restaurant food as well as junk food is not good for babies.
- He was playing tennis as well as swimming on weekends.

And "just as" can mean  "in the same way as":

- Restaurant food isn't good for babies **just as** breast milk isn't fit for adults. [sample from the OP]
- Restaurant food isn't good for babies **in the same way as** breast milk isn't fit for adults

Two different uses of just:
do something just as well as = comparative with an active verb, just makes the comparison more emphatic

just as = in the same way or manner as. It is an idiom and a conjunction.

Here is the full scoop on: ["just as"](https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/how-to-use-just-as-in-a-sentence)

Comment: Am I right that "_Restaurant food isn't good for babies **as well as** breast milk isn't fit for adults_" is incorrect because it means "_Restaurant food isn't good for babies **to the same degree as** breast milk isn't fit for adults_" ?

Comment: As well as = similarly. **Just as well as** = Exactly the same as.

Comment: to the same degree does not mean in the same way or manner. It's grammatical but I don't know if it's true...

Comment: @Loviii - I suppose you invented your example sentence, and I think it is poor because (1) some restaurant food is probably good for some babies (e.g. my local curry place has 'baby bowls' of dal and rice, very suitable for a larger baby), and (2) there is no big reason why adults can't drink human breast milk (they very often drink breast milk from cows, and to a lesser extent from sheep, goats, and mares). Human breast milk has been used in traditional medicine for many years.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  the OP's question is not whether restaurant food is ill-suited for 6 month-old babies or not, we aren't on Biology.SE or Skeptics.SE. The OP's focus is on syntax and semantics. Lambie's example sentences were inspired by those in the question *as well as* WordReference.